# iOS - How to theme UIWebView (or alternatives)?

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview, rss, themes

I'm making a simple RSS reader app. I've managed to get it working (with a hard-coded feed) in such a way that every tableview cell has an article's title.
When you tap on a cell, it opens the article in a webview.

My question is this: how can you theme the webview so that it has a day/sepia/night theme?
Subclassing worked for the other parts of the app, but I have no idea how to implement themes for webviews.

The app Reeder manages to do this so it's definitely possible, but that doesn't seem to use webviews, maybe there's a better way?